# Do editors allowing you to view source code in different indent style exist?

Tags: language-agnostic, version-control, editor

This is not a subjective nor an argumentative question but a question that needs a yes/no answer and, if the answer is positive, the name(s) of said editor(s).

Imagine the company guideline mandates committed code to use the K&R style and that I prefer Allman (for example). Are there editors (either standalone or part of an IDE) that allow you to always "view" your source code using the Allman style, yet always save the file using the K&R style?

It doesn't seem that far-fetched nor that complicated: the source code/text file would always be saved using the "official" style, but what the editor would show you on-screen wouldn't be exactly your text file but a "view" of your text file using the indent style of your choice.  And hence every developer would be free to choose the indent style he/she preferred.

Does an editor (either standalone or integrated with an IDE) that does this exist?

Note that I'm really asking if there exist editor(s) that do this, *not* if there are workflows allowing one to do something similar (for example suggesting to me to use GNU *indent* before doing my Mercurial *hg commit* is *not* anywhere near an answer to the question).

Comment: I'd be interested in this too..

Comment: Would a pair of hooks to run GNU indent in the editor after-load and before-save count as "workflows allowing one to do something similar", or "editor support"?

Comment: I've maintained for years that a combination of that and a compiler that requires an unreadable style (and thus making such an IDE totally necessary) is the ONLY way to end style wars. (And yes, I am joking, a little)

Comment: @BCS: lol :)   It's cool to see an "old" question regularly getting an upvote here and there.  The "unreadable style" is a good one.  Here we've got a mix of IntelliJ IDEA fans (for Java development) and Eclipse fans (and I myself use both IntelliJ IDEA and Emacs) working on different OSes, with different preferred formatting style and I realized it's not *that* far fetched.  But in a way this would end the "style wars" and it would be a huge loss: they're such a big part of our coding-folklore :)

Comment: Commenting on my old question: it's amazing to see that the smart dudes at Google, once again, came up with something that makes this point moot: the formatting of the source code of their "Go" language is spec'ed.  Which means the retarded "arguing" about whether '{' should go on a new line or not is over: '{' does **not** go on a newline in the 'Go' language and you **cannot** do anything about it.  This is wonderful, if only every single language had been spec'ed that way :)

Comment: @syntax I'm not sure I follow your comment. Didn't you say your preferred style is Allman(opening-brace on newline)? Wouldn't a language that enforces the K&R style conflict with how you prefer to view code? How is this conflict wonderful?

Comment: @Victor T.: specs are wonderful.  They precede people's little egoistical views.  For example you may prefer the *while* keyword to be name *dowhilepleez* but that's not what C/C++/C#/Java allows: you have to use *while* and not *dowhilepleez*.  And this is wonderful, even though it conflicts with what you like best.

Comment: @syntax I suppose your comment threw me a bit. I was under the impression that you posed this question because you were seeking an editor that allowed automatic transparent conversion between your preferred style and the conforming style(like newline endings '\r\n') -- as sort of a way to have your cake and eat it too. I wasn't sure how the gofmt tool fits into this. From what I can tell it's just a preprocessing tool similar to GNU's indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim allows you to specify exactly how you want it's indenting to work. Check out:

```
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values
```

Once it is specified, re-indent the whole document with:

```
1G=G
```

Then all you need is to write a macro to set indent style, re-indent and save and another one that autoloads the correct indent style when opening a file.

Comment: You'll need an extra layer of logic no insure that you can save an unmodified file without `q!`. Similar trick could be played in emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Age for Java had a similar feature: Its internal SCM stored the content of your Java sources in a non-text format that kept all the information that's important for the compiler. Each developer could decide how exactly he'd like to view the Java sources.

This included viewing methods/fields without the surrounding class and also the ability to use any code layout you'd like (including custom ones).

[This page](http://javadude.com/vaj/resources/custom-formatters.html) explains how to write a custom formatter. Unfortunately I couldn't find any screenshots of this feature in action.

Answer (score -1):

No.